# How do you send a patch request from a c# client?

Tags: c#, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have a powershell script that does this :

```
    $uri = "$($tfsUri)/$($teamproject)/_apis/build/builds/$($buildID)?api-version=2.0"
    $data = @{keepForever = $keepForever} | ConvertTo-Json
    $response = $webclient.UploadString($uri,"PATCH", $data)
```

I'm trying to rewrite this in C#, using a Webclient.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
string reply = client.UploadString(url, "keepForever = true");
Console.WriteLine(reply);
```

But I get : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

This is TFS 2015 VNext, if that helps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing the METHOD in your call to [UploadString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0d3595k(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
string reply = client.UploadString(url, "keepForever = true");
```

should be:

```
string reply = client.UploadString(url, "PATCH", "keepForever = true");
```

A 401 is unauthorised, so also see if there is a step before in your Powershell where you are logging in or joining a session, you would need to replicate that in your C#.

Answer (score 2):

In order to send a PATCH request you can use `WebClient.UploadData`.

```
string data = "keepForever = true";
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
string reply = client.UploadData(url, "PATCH", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
Console.WriteLine(reply);
```

Comment: One correction on the `string reply` line of code: 
client.UploadData [returns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploaddata?view=netframework-4.5.2#System_Net_WebClient_UploadData_System_String_System_Byte___) a `byte[]`, not string.